# How to initialize array of vector of objects

Tags: c++, hashtable

I am fairly new to C++ and trying to implement a simple HashTable using pointer to vectors (so that I can do chaining on collisions). I am not sure if I am going about this totally wrong way.

How would I construct HashTable of given size in the constructor below?

Thanks.

```
class HashTable
{
public:
    HashTable(size_t size)
    {
         // ? how do i create an array of vector of entry object of size size
    }
private:  
    class Entry
    {
    public:
        Entry(string key, int value) : _key(key), _value(value) {}
        ~Entry(){}
    private:
        string _key;
        int _value;
        friend class HashTable;
    };

    vector<Entry>* _table;
    size_t _size;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a `typedef` for `Bucket`, which is a list of `Entry` objects.
Store a list of `Bucket`s in the hash table.

```
class HashTable
{
   public:
      HashTable(size_t size) : _table(size) // Initialize the table given the size
      {                                     // There is no need to keep the size
      }                                     // as member data.
   private:  
      class Entry
      {
         public:
            Entry(string key, int value) : _key(key), _value(value) {}
            ~Entry(){}
         private:
            string _key;
            int _value;
            friend class HashTable;
      };

      // Create a typedef for a bucket, which is a list of `Entry`s.
      std::vector<Entry> Bucket;

      // Store a list of Buckets.
      std::vector<Bucket> _table;
}
```

Comment: Hi, is the size not needed because you are now using a vector of vectors?

Comment: Can you please explain why vector of vector would be better than using an array of vectors for hash table? Thanks!

Comment: @joonho Automatic memory management, same ease of access as array.

Answer (score 2):

```
HashTable(size_t size) : _table(new vector<Entry>[size]), _size(size) {}
```